# Bulk changing content of place field (e.g. search and replace) using Gramps

Tags: gramps

Can I bulk change the content of the place field in GRAMPS genealogy software?

I am discovering a lot of errors since I started using (trying to use) the "enclosed by" feature.  Now I need to fix a few and would like to do that with a search and replace.

Comment: which version of gramps and can you give an example of what you want to fix?